# What is the Islamic perspective on space colonization?

Tags: sharia, sunni, spirituality

What is the Islamic perspective on space colonization? and do you guys  believe that Islam would spread to other planets in space?Furthermore, where would Islam have prayed to the sun if the Earth had been completely destroyed? and do Muslims believe that there are other living forms? If Muslims learned that other living things exist, would their faith be altered? And how would the government operate if Islam were to take control of a space civilization? Would it adhere to the same Islamic principles or would it adopt new ones? Since I write science fiction, I'm interested in learning more about Islam. I've been studying Islam for the past year, so these kinds of questions spark my interest.

Comment: I once met a member of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jehovah%27s_Witnesses and he told me that gods commands were only meant for the planet earth. I have no idea how his opinion was backed up, or if perhaps only an individual thought.